# php sqlite - copy table to another database

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to copy table from another db file but I fail and I can't get why. This is my code:

```
 $db = new SQLite3($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/db/098765.db");
 $sql = "ATTACH DATABASE 'admin.db' AS admin ;
         INSERT INTO 'table-1' SELECT * FROM 'admin.table-1';";
 $db->query($sql);
```

I've read all the questions on this topic on this site, but no answer helped me.

Giving the full path to ATTACH DATABASE doesn't work. Creating table before inserting data also doesn't work.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to do it via `php`?

Comment: Preferably, but I'm open to any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `sqlite3` command line tool has a handy command called `.dump` that makes this task trivial:

```
sqlite3 admin.db '.dump "table-1"' | sqlite3 098765.db
```

This will create the table, all associated indexes and of course it will copy all the data.

**Edit**: For a more general solution, create a shell script (let's call it `copy-table.sh`) as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
$src_db="$1"
$dst_db="$2"
$table="$3"

sqlite3 "$src_db" ".dump \"$table\"" | sqlite3 "$dst_db"
```

Then you can execute the script as follows

```
./copy-table.sh 'admin.db' '098765.db' 'table-1'
```

Obviously, you can execute the script anyway you want, e.g. from cron or from php.

Comment: I need this script to be executed automatically. Is it possible with command line tools?

Comment: Yes. Is it always the same table, i.e. `table-1` and the same databases?

Comment: No, it differs.

Comment: I execute it via shell_exec, but it doesn't do anything. My code `$dbPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; echo shell_exec("sh $dbPath/db/copy-table.sh 'admin.db' '098765.db' 'table-1'");`

Comment: Does it give an error? What about if you execute in the terminal. Note that you have to give the full paths to the databases, e.g. `shell_exec("sh $dbPath/db/copy-table.sh '$dbPath/admin.db' '$dbPath/098765.db' 'table-1'");`

Answer (score 0):

1. Properly quote database object identifiers (table/column names etc) in your `INSERT` statement. Use use [double quotes](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) instead of single ones, which are for string literals. Better yet don't use dashes or other restricted characters in object names if possible (stick with alphanumerics and underscore).
2. Use `exec()` instead of `query()`

```php
$dbPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$adminDbPath = $dbPath; // Or something else

$db = new SQLite3("$dbPath/db/098765.db");
$db->exec("ATTACH DATABASE '$adminDbPath/admin.db' AS admin");
$db->exec('INSERT INTO "table-1" SELECT * FROM admin."table-1"');
     ^^^^              ^       ^                     ^       ^
```

Comment: Warning: SQLite3::exec(): no such table: table-1

Comment: You won't get this warning message if you properly double quote the table name `"table-1"`.

Comment: I did everything exactly as you wrote.

Comment: Apparently not. There are two possibilities: either you didn't properly quoted table names or the table has a different name in one or both databases. Can you post your code after all edits?

Comment: I copied yours and double checked it. I also tried CREATE TABLE ... AS, it says that there is no such table : admin.table-1.

Comment: This means that you're trying to insert duplicate values from `admin.db` database. Or in other words you already have rows with these values in your target database `098765.db`.

Comment: Your answer is correct! BUT, the error `UNIQUE constraint failed` is caused when there is a primary key column in the original table. AND you should do `CREATE TABLE "table-1" AS SELECT * FROM admin."table-1"`, because if you INSERT INTO, it will copy the content of `admin."table-1"` into itself (double the content of `admin."table-1"`). AND it should be `ATTACH DATABASE '$dbPath/db/admin.db'`. Please update your answer and I will mark it as CORRECT.

Answer (score 0):

You can get exact copy of table by performing the following set of SQL statements:

(In context of connection to destination database)

```
attach '<source-db-full-name>' as sourceDb;
select sql from 'sqlite_master' where type = 'table' and name = '<name-of-table>';

// Execute result of previous statement. 
// It will create empty table with 
// schema identical to schema of source table

insert into '<name-of-table>' select * from sourceDb.[<name-of-table>];
detach sourceDb;
```